# Load balance UDP and TCP traffic to different servers based on source

Tags: nginx, routing, load-balancing

We have a use case where we need to have a load-balancer that can handle both TCP and UDP traffic for multiple backends. We want to route traffic based on the source network. For example like this:

```
Customer A (192.168.1.0/24) -> Load Balancer -> Backend1
Customer B (192.168.2.0/27) -> Load Balancer -> Backend2
```

We have used nginx in the past and would like to use it again if possible, some pseudo configuration of how we imagine it would look like:

```
stream {
    upstream customerA {
        server backend1:514;
    }
    upstream customerB {
        server backend2:514;
    }

    server {
        listen 514;
    if ($source_ip == '192.168.1.0/24') {
       proxy_pass customerA;
       }
    if ($source_ip == '192.168.2.0/27') {
       proxy_pass customerB;
       }
    }
}
```

I am aware of this thread: [Nginx TCP stream routing based on source IP](https://serverfault.com/questions/763790/nginx-tcp-stream-routing-based-on-source-ip) however there are comments suggesting that it would not work.

How can we achieve this?

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_map_module.html stream map module available since 1.11.2, so this will work

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyTen, i'm having a hard time figuring out how to implement it like the example i have provided in the OP. Could you perhaps provide an example with using the map module?